# How to duplicate these animated Tentacles?

Tags: animation, rigging

I made one tentacle work, but there should be 5 of them. What is the practice method to duplicate them? I tried to use Instances, and they did not work. Thanks, all!

There is the blender file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: parent the object + armature to an empty, move and rotate the empty the way you want, parent it to the main object?

Comment: if moonboots answer doesn't work, pls provide blend file

Comment: @moonboots, I tried that, but when the IK's location changes, the claw does not open correctly.

Comment: @Chris the blender file is uploaded to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

1. hide body
2. select all (box select)
3. press SHIFT-D and move
4. test out whether all works as expected

[image]

Comment: I tried your way, but the claw does not move correctly along with the Body, and tentacles are detached from the Body. I will show you later.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have found one way to make these Tentacles work.

1. Duplicate the entire Tentacle
2. Reparent the IK targets and curves.

The solution is not perfect because this guy only has 5 tentacles. If he has 20, I have to repeat this process 20 times. If anyone has an easier way to reduce the workflow, please advise.

Thanks for the suggestions from @Chris and @Moonboots.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand the solution, could you please post pictures of the process?